# Failure initializing default SSL context

Tags: java, json, rest, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am making a call to `REST URL` and trying to measure how much time it is taking to get the response back.

I am using `DefaultHttpClient` for that to get the response back from `REST URL`.

In my below program , each thread will be working on a particular range. Like Each Thread will work between `1 - 100` and second thread will work between `101 - 200` etc.

So in my below code, it is working sometime for me but after sometime it throws me exception as

```
Failure initializing default SSL context
```

And this error as well-

```
I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing here?- Or I can use any better clients apart from `DefaultHttpClient` to make RESTFUL call.

Below is my code-

```
class Task implements Runnable {

private DefaultHttpClient httpclient;
private HttpResponse response;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            for (int userId = id; userId < id + noOfTasks; userId++) {

                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

               HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/service/BEService/v1/get/USERID=10000/profile.ACCOUNT.SERVICE");

                long start = System.nanoTime();

                response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

                long end = System.nanoTime() - start;

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                EntityUtils.consume(entity);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Threw a Exception in " + getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
        } finally {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
    }
}
```

If there is anything wrong with my code. How can I improve it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything specifically wrong with your code but that error message you're seeing sounds more like an OS level error.

There was another article that might answer this for you: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2577795